# Multiple Interfaces - Just need 1's ID

Tags: c#-4.0, interface

I have a dynamic collection of Interfaces in c#
the collection is loose - not bound to a List / Dictionary / etc.

but at any given time does only 1 of the interfaces have a valid nested class "ID" (Guid)

so, to avoid to the repetative task of duplicating all conditions jsut to validate the actual id. Is there a quicker / efficient way of determining the ID from a single interface ?

for instance:

```
ICookies;
IBread;
IJar;

if (ICookies.BaseObject.ID != null)
   this.ID = ICookies.BaseObject.ID

if (IBread.BaseObject.ID != null)
   this.ID = IBread.BaseObject.ID

if (IJar.BaseObject.ID != null)
   this.ID = IJar.BaseObject.ID

.... etc. etc.
```

Comment: If you don't have your objects in a collection, there's not much you can do to avoid repetetive code.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your code, like:

```
this.ID = ICookies.BaseObject.ID ?? IBread.BaseObject.ID ?? IJar.BaseObject.ID;
```

Comment: The interfaces are witin 1 class, i was thinking calling reflection on that class and populate them from there